# Transitive closure in category setting

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question, higher-category-theory

Let $\mathscr C$ be a category so that every morphism is '*invertible*' only up to equivalence and so that it makes sense to say two morphisms are '*homotopic to each other*'. Probably this is called $(2,1)$-category.

(The category in my mind could be such that objects are topological spaces and morphisms are homotopy equivalence maps)

Let $\mathscr D$ be a full subcategory of $\mathscr C$.

Given an object $X\in\mathscr C\setminus \mathscr D$, I attempt to construct a binary relation $\sim_X$ imitating the [transitive closure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transitive+closure) in the set theory. Namely, a pair $(c,d )$ in the set $X$ is related, denoted by $c\sim_X d$, if the following holds:

*There exists a sequence $c=c_0,c_1,\dots, c_{n-1},c_n=d$ for an integer $n\ge 0$ so that for every $0\le i\le n-1$ and every pair $(c_i,c_{i+1})$ we may find an object $Y_i\in\mathscr D$, an element $a$ in the set $Y_i$, and two morphisms $f_i^{(0)}, f_i^{(1)}:Y_i\to X$, which are 'homotopic to each other', satisfying $f_i^{(0)}(a)=c_i$ and $f_i^{(1)}(a)=c_{i+1}$.*

> **Question**: It seems that this construction gives an equivalence relation on every object set $X$. Is there a categorical generalization of transitive closure?

Since in category setting people often talk about congruence relations rather than equivalence relations. Perhaps this is related to some higher congruence things like [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28n%2Cr%29-congruence)?

Comment: What kind of formalism for ∞-groupoids are you using? I am struggling to turn your question in a meaningful mathematical statement. I don't even know what "assume that every object is a set" means (do you mean you have some kind of functor to sets?)

Comment: @DenisNardin Sorry for the confusion. Maybe I am using the wrong terminology, I am not familiar with the categorical languages. The category in my mind is a one so that objects are topological spaces and morphisms are homotopy equivalence maps. So in this case, a topological space is a set, and I want to introduce a relation on it.

Comment: Maybe you want a $(2,1)$-category?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you. Probably you are right, I made some edits accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every morphism is a equivalence, then you really want a $(2,0)$-category, also known as a 2-groupoid. However, I see no reason to assume every morphism is an equivalence here.

This is not a generalization or a categorification of a transitive closure, in any case: it is literally the transitive closure of the relation $R$ on $X$ defined as $xRy$ if there exists $A\in \mathscr D$, $a\in A$, and homotopic maps $f,g:A\to X$ such that $f(a)=x$ and $g(a)=y$. This is closely analogous to the relation that $x$ and $y$ are in the same connected component, if $X$ is a topological space-indeed if a one-point space is in $\mathscr D$ then they are the same relation, and $R$ is already transitive.